# jQuery / WP - Animation depending on different pages

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm making this website, where I want to have a quote shown on the homepage, and hide that on other pages. I'm using WordPress to make this website.

So, I was thinking about the WP function is_home() and than use a jQuery function, but that didn't work.

It's probably something really simple. I just want a animation effect, that the text disappears and the div where it's in shrinks a bit. And ofcourse vice versa when on 'Home'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was thinking about the WP function is_home() and than use a jQuery function, but that didn't work

Did you try [`is_front_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page)? I think it would be ideal for only including the quote when you want it to display and the jQuery code that animates the quote's container will of course only work when the container it is targeting is on the page.

Comment: Thanks! That works :) Now I only need to make a 'smooth' jQuery animation, instead of the 'hard' change of height. Do you have an idea how to do this?

Comment: I now have this:  `<script type="text/javascript">
  <?php if (is_front_page()) {?>  
   $("#animation").animate({ min-height: "140px" }, 500 );
 <?php } else {?>
   $("#animation").animate({ min-height: "35px" }, 500 );
 <?php } ?> 
 </script>`  but like expected, that doesn't work...

Comment: @priktop - See http://api.jquery.com/animate/ for ideas; regardless of whichever effect / animation you use though, it may seem a little jerky when the page first loads. You might want to start another question with your JavaScript as the focus and use http://jsfiddle.net/ with your current HTML and JavaScript code which people can then use to give you improved animations.

Comment: Alright, at least thanks for all the help :) I'll start a new question like you suggested.